# spring boot actuator endpoints unavailable after (2.5) uprade

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have attempted to take advice offered for similar problems; to no avail. Can someone please explain a resolution for this problem, as if I were six?

I've upgraded my version of spring boot to 2.5. All tests in my suite still pass, except for this @Springboot test:

```
@Test
void readActuatorInfo_success() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
            get("/actuator/info")
                    .header("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA=="))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

It fails because the response is 404. Now, I know that springboot does not, by default, expose the endpoints, that they must be explicitly configured. For example, the following yaml should do it, but no. Any tips?

```
application:
   endpoint:
     info:
       enabled: true
```

To be clear, this test passed for Springboot 2.3

Answer (score 0):

From 2.5 onwards the Info endpoint is no longer exposed by default,

> The /info actuator endpoint is no longer exposed over the web by default. Additionally, if Spring Security is on the classpath and your application doesn’t have a custom security configuration, the endpoint requires authenticated access by default.

> Refer to the documentation on exposing and securing actuator endpoints to change these new defaults.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.5-Release-Notes#secure-info-endpoint

```
management:
   endpoint:
      web:
        exposure: "health,info"
```

Comment: I'm still getting a 404. I am able to confirm that my yaml file is definitely in use, and it contains your config. I'm obviously doing something wrong, I'll start over.

Comment: sorry that is wrong properties is why :) updated

Comment: Thanks, but now I get this: ...Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ...

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
 at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:121)

Comment: please add the full stack and your websecurityconfiguration

Comment: sorry, I reverted everything I was doing because of time constraints.